# Grab the first id out of string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting HTML content retrieved through a string. Now I want only to retrieve the first value of the id, `id3`. Can anyone tell me which expression I should use?

```js
var string = "<div class='test' id='id3'><div class='test2' id='id2'></div></div> ";

grab = string.split(/'/)[1];

$('body').append(grab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var string = "<div class='test' id='id3'><div class='test2' id='id2'></div></div> ";
var element = $(string);
var value = element.attr('id');
console.log(value);  // id3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use it as jquery object then use the class test to get the attribute id

```js
var string = "<div class='test' id='id3'><div class='test2' id='id2'></div></div> ";

grab = $(string+".test").attr('id')

$('body').append(grab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. But if I do not know what the class would be called then this solution might not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a temporary element using `document.createElement`, and using standard JS properties on the new element, get the ID of any of the children of the div.

```js
var string = "<div class='test' id='id3'><div class='test2' id='id2'></div></div> ";

var div =document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = string;
console.log(div);

var grab = div.children[0].id;

$('body').append(grab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you string a a selector then use find() and attr()

var string = " ";
    var id=$(string).find(".test").attr("id");
    console.log(I'd);